# How Do I get Rid Of Form-Group Margin-Left

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I am encountering an issue with this annoying margin that form-group has.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>End Time <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FormModel.EndDateTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker" })
 </div>
```

I have tried

```
.form-group col-md-4 {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

```
.form-group {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

However, when I do

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

It works, but this is unrelated to what I am wanting to do.

Here is what I am wanting to get rid of: [Margin-Left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omqXS.png)

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? And please post a [mcve]

Comment: I am using Boostrap4. And I read that thread and still don't know how to make a reproducible example. Seems a bit overboard for just removing a margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the padding not the margin. I am basing this off of the colours used in the chrome debugger box model. The green bit is margin with the blue content inside.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I don't know how I didn't notice that haha.